# Windows 10 uninstall Mamp - cannot find C:\MAMP\unins000.exe

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mamp

**Short backstory:** Recently I've installed MAMP as I want to start learning PHP. I got version 4.1.1 from the MAMP homepage, Apache didn't start. This seems to be a common bug for that version, I found a solution in downloading version 4.1.0. Both servers started but the Open WebStart Page didn't work.

**My Problem:** I wanted to try reinstalling it, I deleted the MAMP folder, as I thought that would be sufficient, instead of deleting it in the system settings. Now when I download it again and start the installer it says

> MAMP setup has detected existing MAMP installation. You need to remove existing installation before proceeding. Do you want to uninstall it now?

Clicking either yes or no gives me

> MAMP setup will now exit and the existing MAMP installation will not be removed.

In the system settings I find

> MAMP & MAMP PRO 4.1.0 version 4.1.0 (1.47 GB)

When trying to uninstall it it gives me this error

> Windows cannot find 'C:\MAMP\unins000.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

**Is there any way, other than reinstalling my whole OS, to solve this problem or do I have to turn to a different web server app?**

Comment: Why oh why oh why did you delete that folder? Since when has that ever been the way to uninstall anything?

Comment: Use Laragon if u are under windows OS
https://laragon.org/

Comment: Open the registry and search for mamp and delete everything you find.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem and I hope my solution works for you as well:

Just download the .exe file into another device and install the MAMP.

After a successful installation, just copy the folder to your original device that has the problem.

And then you should find a file with a name starting with "uni" meaning it is for uninstallation. Just run that file and then everything should be fine!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (on OS is windows 10).

I browse the web and found a way:

You can download the [ccleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) and use it, it can delete the MAMP.